# R: Writing data frame to text using grouping

Tags: r

I got stuck while trying to get my data into the correct output format. The original data consists of a table with two columns: (1) groupname (2) mailadress, e.g.

```
groupname   mailadress
group1      dummy1@gmail.com
group1      dummy2@hotmail.com
group2      bla@gmail.com
group2      jdoe@yahoo.com
```

But I need the data in the following format and saved as a text file:

```
# group1
dummy1@gmail.com
dummy2@hotmail

# group2
bla@gmail.com
jdoe@yahoo.com
```

I know there must be a way to achieve this using `dplyr`, e.g. `group_walk()`, but I've currently run out of ideas... Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: To be clear, you need to write the data to a text file in that format? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, a text file is required as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found one possible solution. Say the `data.frame`is `df`:

```
export <- df %>% select(groupname, mailadress) %>% group_by(groupname) %>% 
  +     mutate(mails = paste0(mailadress, collapse = "\n")) %>% slice(1) %>% select(groupname, mails)
export$groupname<- paste0("# ",export$groupname)
write.table(export, "export.txt", sep = "\n", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = F)
```

Comment: Are you sure this produces the output as indicated in the question?

Comment: Why do you think it won't produce the output as required in the question? Remember, I asked the question myself. And later I found a solution that works for my specific need.

Comment: For me, there are missing the blank lines as indicated in the question. The line just above #group2.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~groupname, ~mailadress,
  "group1", "dummy1@gmail.com",
  "group1", "dummy2@hotmail.com",
  "group2", "bla@gmail.com",
  "group2", "jdoe@yahoo.com"
)


df %>%
  split(df$groupname) %>%
  map(
    ~paste0("# ", .x$groupname[1], "\n", paste(.x$mailadress, collapse = "\n"))
      ) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  paste(collapse = "\n\n") %>%
  cat(file = "output.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time answering!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i got what you want

```
x<-df%>%filter(groupname =="group1")%>%select(mailadress)

names(x)<-"group1"
write.table(x, file = "X.txt", sep = "\t",
            row.names = FALSE)
```

but this wil output

```
"group1"
"dummy1@gmail.com"
"dummy2@hotmail.com"
```

if its not the point tell me better so i can help